# Select field resets when the page resets

Tags: html, forms, select, reset

I wrote a code which user can select an option in select field. and it have `onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"` 
on select tag and every option tag have own value.

So my question is this:

when I select an option from this select field, it sends query string to the same page and I want to my selected option keep selected but the select field is reset when page reset.
it's wasn't such and was work true, but I think I make some change in my code (which I can't find that) and that makes the problem.

here is my code:

```
                    <?php

                    parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

                    require ('../config.php');
                     /* connect and select db codes*/

                    $dbresult=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM services");

                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbresult)){
                            $order_name = $row['name'];
                            $order_id = $row['id'];
                            echo "<option value=\"NewOrder.php?service=$order_id&quantity=1th\">$order_name</option>";
                    }
                    ?>

                            </select><br/>


  /* ...continue of my codes...*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify that the option is selected in an attribute.
So for the option that you want to select, you need to add the `selected="selected"` attribute

In PHP this could be done with something like this before your echo statement, it will select this option if the order id is the same as the order id specified in the query string

```
  if($service == $order_id){
     $selected = "selected";
  }
  else{
     $selected = "";
  }
```

and in your echo statement

```
   echo "<option value=\"NewOrder.php?service=$order_id&quantity=1th\" ".$selected.">$order_name</option>";
```